# How to print a list of all commiters since branch creation

Tags: git

I am looking to print a single list of all users that committed on a branch since it was created from the master (or even as far back as master creation)

I've looked at git log and I don't see such an option.

Even if I was to use git log, I just want to print an entire list without having to tab through it so that I can output it to a file.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To show a list of all committers you can use this command

```
$ git shortlog -sn
```

Output will be similar to

```
42  DJ180
1   Tim Castelijns
```

Naturally this first lists the number of commits and then the person who committed.
In this case I made 1 commit and you made 42

---

To list only the committers of the commits in the current master branch:

```
$ git shortlog -sn master
```

---

To list only the committers of the branch `branchname` since it branched off of master:

```
$ git shortlog -sn master..branchname
```

This one makes use of the so called revision range:

> <**revision range**>
>
> Show only commits in the specified revision range.
>   When no  is specified, it defaults to HEAD (i.e. the
>   whole history leading to the current commit). origin..HEAD specifies
>   all the commits reachable from the current commit (i.e. HEAD), but not
>   from origin.

---

More info at http://git-scm.com/docs/git-shortlog

That shows you can for example add a `-e` parameter to include the email addresses of the committers.